# angularjs How to make method call itself in controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, frontend

So, my question, is how to make controller method call itself( its defined in controller constructor ), for example:

```
this.getExportPath = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(1);
        return getExportPath();
    }, 1);
}
```

I have tryed:

```
this.getExportPath();
getExportPath();
return getExportPath();
return this.getExportPath();
```

Help would be appriciated.

Comment: `var getExportPath = function() { .. }` then `getExportPath();` ..?

Comment: But then i cant call the fucntion outside of construcotr.

Comment: Do you mean you want to do a recursive call to the function?

Comment: You could just use `$interval`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that `this` is not the current object.  Typically, you want to assign `self` to `this` at the begginng of the controller and use self instead of this

So..

```
var self = this;
self.getExportPath = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        self.getExportPath();
    },1)
}
```